# How can I sort data every n-th line in linux?

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, sed

I have following data.

```
 ...
 4080 2 2 3236 4079 0         0.869         0.872         1.863         2.000        -0.720
 3654 2 2 3653 3655 0         0.864         0.873         1.798         2.000        -0.676
 3653 1 1 3654 0         0.864         0.977         0.000         0.422
 3655 1 1 3654 0         0.873         0.895         0.000         0.404
 ...
```

Data has total 100000000 lines, made up of 100000 data blocks, and each of them have 1000 lines per data block.

I hope to sort data within the data blocks, which means, sort every 1000th line. Sort 1~1000, 1001~2000 ... like this, with respect to first column values. Like

```
...
 1 4 4 263 704 952 244 0         0.951         0.941         0.928         0.936         3.836         0.000         1.668
 2 4 4 33 215 305 172 0         0.937         0.942         0.945         0.924         3.815         0.000         1.574
 3 4 4 279 344 377 1945 0         0.928         0.934         0.938         0.920         3.830         0.000         1.502
...
```

Can I do this with awk, sed, and sort of linux, to sort every n-th lines using m-th column values? I know 'sort -nk m file > output' can do a sort, but how can I do this for every n-th line? Should I need to use for loop?

---

#### Solved

I found the answer from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99582/sorting-blocks-of-lines. I didn't even need to use for loop, used AWK commands to do this.

Comment: Yes. For more help, post a brief example with, say, 9 input lines of 3 columns each, and sorting in groups of 3 lines. Show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\n/&/1000;Ta;s/.*/echo "&" | sort/e' file
```

This gathers every 1000 lines then applies a sort to them.